# Do I need to use a bonding agent between scratch and base coat plaster on the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, plaster, lath-and-plaster

I'm doing a traditional 3-coat plaster over wooden lath to repair a 4x4 hole on an interior ceiling.

I'm using StructoLite base coat plaster.

I applied Plaster Weld to the lath prior to putting up the scratch coat, but I wondered if it is necessary or helpful to use the bonding agent between base coat and scratch coat, especially as it on the ceiling. I thought it might improve the bond, but I haven't seen a many references to doing this, and the product was invented after the heyday of 3-coat plaster systems.

Is it necessary to wet the scratch coat prior to putting up the base coat otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a bonding agent, for putting a base coat on a scratch coat, or a finish coat on a base.   However you do need to make sure you scratched the scratch coat properly, and you do need to dampen an existing coat of plaster before you put on the new wet plaster.  If you don't dampen the existing plaster first, it will dry out before setting, and you'd have to dampen it afterwards and hope that it sets enough to be usable.

Just wanted to add, you didn't say how you were going to do the finish coat, but from experience you do NOT want to use gauging plaster and lime putty without adding some perlite fines.  If you don't add the fines, on a lightweight aggregated base plaster, the finish coat will develop cracks upon drying. I don't believe this is a problem, if you are not using hydrated lime and gauging plaster for finish coat.

Comment: Most base mixes have an add mix in them saying an add mix is not needed like saying you have never done stucco, sure it’s my opinion but add mixes in each layer increase the not only the bond but the life. There are dozens of different brands most are at least 80-90% the same components with water being the largest single variable. You put the add mix in the mix it creates a stronger and more flexible bond that is less likely to crack.

Comment: @EdBeal, Ed this isn't exterior stucco, I don't know your region but when we say plaster in the US it means interior gypsum with or without lime.  I'm not saying an additive wouldn't help or improve the outcome in some way, just that it isn't necessary to get the coats to adhere to each other.

Comment: where did I say it needed to be exterior? Add mix reduces cracking in both internal and external use. And no there is real stucco pressed into expanded metal interior walls not just scratch coat or skim coats,  I just came from a house in the California Bay Area that has this exact type of stucco inside. But even skim coats are better with ad mix added.

Comment: @EdBeal, ... and where did I say "add mix", I didn't... you inferred that from a question about bonding agent.  If I was doing stucco, because it contains cement, I'd be using a bonding agent on every coat also.  If you like using an additive, in your mix, I'm not telling you to stop. ... I'd actually like to know which one you add, to see if I should be using it also.

Comment: Add mix is the bond promoter that pros use. As I said someone that has limited experience probably is unaware of this.

Comment: Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use an add mix in my stucco, thinset and mortar. Add mix increases the bond, reduces cracking and seals better. Other than this I have not used any bonding additives on stucco between coats.

Comment: I working with structolite plaster on an interior ceiling

Comment: What add mix do you use BTW?  Something like sikalatex?

Comment: Gbronner interior or exterior having a better bond that is more flexible is always a plus. Read the ingredients many modern bag mixes have some add mix already in them the higher the content the more expensive why you can hydrate with add mix alone, expensive but it will provide the best bond and least cracking.